# How Can I Apply TAX Rule Based On Individual SKU Wise - Taxable Goods

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sku, taxes

I need to apply the tax rate for my all products with the unique tax rate, Tax rate different from each other, I mean all products have the own tax rate. How can I solve it?

Comment: Without creating a module that will hook into tax calculations your only options is to create product tax class separate for each product and use that product tax classes in creating tax rules per product tax class.

Comment: After created product tax class, could you pls briefly explain next step?

Comment: Check at this tutorial, it shows all parts: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/magento_setup_taxes.htm

Comment: @Zefiryn: I am already studied tutorialspoint.com tutorial, it's showed only based on country and state, not for individual sku based tax

Comment: In Step (2) you are defining product tax class. I assume you are having this created. Set up Tax Rates shows you how to create a single tax rate. This is dependent on country and zip code (state). Here you need to create all rates you want to ever use. Then in Setup Tax Rules you need to combine both previous steps. Create Rules for each product tax class and each tax rule. In that form you have fields for Product tax class and tax rule to be use.

Comment: I don't want to create tax rate based on country and zip code (state), here i need setup tax rate based on individual products, is possible?

Comment: No, you have to use country and zip for rate. This is what product tax class is for, to set different rates to different products. If you have many countries then you will need to create rates for all of them. Or you can try to search for a module that changes the tax rule behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61091/discussion-between-rathinam-and-zefiryn).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61091/discussion-between-rathinam-and-zefiryn

Comment: @Zefiryn: 
Actually, I am sale products only in India, I need to apply the tax for every product, the tax is differentiated from each other, eg like books have some of the tax, metal has some of the tax, cloth products have some of the tax. that's why I need to apply the tax for every product.

Comment: and thats why you generate tax  rates: one for books , one for metals etc and later when creating a product you assign a rate to it .

Comment: @AntonS : could you pls share any refer link

Comment: this is all described in magento user manual

Answer (score -1):

Login to Magento backend and navigate to Sales -> Tax-> Manage Tax Zones & Rates.
Add then create the tax rule by navigating to Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules -> Add New Tax Rule. 
Use above Tax rule while creating your product.

Comment: How can I give my individual product tax rate?